# Destroy/replace thread on timer or command outside from the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, server

Currently I'm working on server development for an online game and decided to implement it as multithreaded application.

I have a main thread which implements `while` loop which abstractly gets data from the socket.

```
std::vector<std::thread> games_threads;

int start(int game_id) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    return end(game_id);
}

int end(int game_id) {
    // some other conditions for turn end
    return start(game_id);
}

int main() {
    // socket implmementation
    while(1) {
      Message msg = socket.get_data();
      switch(msg->action) {
         case GAME_START:
             std::thread game_thread(start, create_game());
             game_thread.detach();
             games_threads.push_back(game_thread);
             break;
         case TURN_END:
             std::thread game_thread(end, msg->get_game());
             game_thread.detach();
             games_threads.push_back(game_thread);
             break;
      }
    }
}
```

Game creates with turn `start()` method. And then after waiting 10 secs in call `end()` method which implements turn end.

After than turn `end()` method calls `start()`.

But I need also implement force turn end method so I have race condition with 2 cases:

- Start -> End normal workflow with 10s timeout (which makes game
  thread unavailable for 10 secs)
- Forced turn end command (`TURN_END`).

So I need somehow end the current game thread and replace with one user thread. Or just catch signals somehow with conditional variable but I have already freeze for 10sec and as far as I know I can't wait both things at the same time (conditional variable and sleep ending).

Maybe multithreading is not a good solution at all. Please share your approach in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not so much that multi-threading is a bad approach as your specific implementation is not right.

A call to the `start()` function or `end()` function will never return because they each call each other in a never ending recursion. This is already bad since your stack will be filling up as you enter deeper into function calls.

But that aside, your main loop starts a new thread when you call `GAME_START` and this new thread goes into its "forever" `start()<-->end()` loop. "OK" so far, but then when the `TURN_END` is called your **main** loop calls `end()` directly and therefore your main loop also now enters a forever `start()<-->end()` loop. This now means both your main and your "worker" thread are locked up in these loops that don't return - so no more messages can be processed from your socket.

I would suggest that your main loop uses a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to signal your worker loop to force a new turn.

I am not quite sure what to suggest to replace your `start()<-->end()` recursion loop because its not clear to me what this is trying to achieve. But possibly a [timer class](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/) might work here (the example is the first one I found in google)

**Complete Example Using Stdin**

Here the start function implements a thread loop instead of calling end/start repeatedly... Also the game ID 1 gets ended when you enter `end` the other games continue as normal. All games exit when you enter `exit`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>


std::vector<std::thread> games_threads;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int the_game_id = 0;

int start(int id) {
    int game_id = id;
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();    
        std::cout << "THREAD " << game_id << ": Waiting for turn..." << std::endl;
        // Wait for the signal to end turn only if the game ID is for us.
        if(cv.wait_until(lk, now + std::chrono::seconds(10), [&game_id](){return (the_game_id == game_id || the_game_id == -1);}))
        {
            // Condition var signalled
            if (the_game_id == -1)
            {
                std::cout << "THREAD" << game_id << ": end game - exit" << std::endl;
                running = false;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "THREAD" << game_id << ": turn end forced" << std::endl;
                // Reset the game ID so we don't keep triggering
                the_game_id = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // 10 second timeout occured
            std::cout << "THREAD" << game_id << ": 10 seconds is up, end turn" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "THREAD" << game_id << ": ended" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    // pretend socket implmementation - using stdin
    int id = 1;
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
        std::string cmd;
        std::getline(std::cin, cmd);
        if (cmd == "start")
        {
            std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;           
            games_threads.push_back({ std::thread( [&id](){ return start(id++); } ) });
        }
        else if (cmd == "end")
        {
            std::cout << "ending..." << std::endl;
            // Notify game ID 1 to end turn - (but in reality get the ID from the message)
            the_game_id = 1;
            cv.notify_all();
        }
        else if (cmd == "exit")
        {
            std::cout << "exiting all threads..." << std::endl;
            // Notify game ID 1 to end turn
            the_game_id = -1;
            cv.notify_all();
            done = true;
        }        
    }

    // Tidyup threads
    for (auto &th : games_threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> start
starting...
THREAD 1: Waiting for turn...

> start
starting...
THREAD 2: Waiting for turn...

> start
starting...
THREAD 3: Waiting for turn...

> end
ending...
THREAD1: turn end forced
THREAD 1: Waiting for turn...

THREAD2: 10 seconds is up, end turn
THREAD 2: Waiting for turn...
THREAD3: 10 seconds is up, end turn
THREAD 3: Waiting for turn...
THREAD1: 10 seconds is up, end turn
THREAD 1: Waiting for turn...

> exit
exiting all threads...
THREAD1: end game - exit
THREAD1: ended
THREAD2: end game - exit
THREAD2: ended
THREAD3: end game - exit
THREAD3: ended
```

Comment: but I can't do that simple. Because I have "sleep_for" call and can't use `cv.wait` anymore. So I have 10seconds gap which is bad... PS. I updated my question and replaced main thread by creating new worker.

Comment: Then you can use `wait_until(...)` which means you can wait until your condition variable "triggers" or some timeout (like 10 seconds) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I didn't know about this method. But what about this solution at all. Is that okay that I will destroy current game thread in favor of new  one for the same game?

Comment: hmmm... So you code change now means that your system won't lock up, but now you just have two threads running your start/end loop. I think you only ever want 1 thread doing that. So, no I would say don't call start or end directly more then once since they should be in a different thread. You should not communicate between threads by direct function calls. The method to communicate between threads is via condition variables and mutex's. I will attempt to put up an example for you in the answer but it will be untested code, give me 5 minutes...

Comment: It would be amazing honestly. Because I'm not quite sure how I can manage couple game threads with conditional variables.

Comment: @featureoffuture try that... its a start point, but I really strongly suggest you also remove the recursion - but maybe that is for another question : )

Comment: but `cv.notify_all()` will just tell to all my games force end turns, right? If so I need something like mapping between conditional variables and games/threads, right?

Comment: @featureoffuture not necessarily. Once you have your signal working, you can also set a flag. Lets say its an `enum {start, stop, other_action, etc...}`. You set the flag, then trigger cv. Then in your wait_until you can inspect the value of the flag and take the appropriate action...

Comment: in my case I have "game_id" which is integer and I know that and I only need to call `end()` for a particular thread / games. So how can I pass variable to particular game thread with game_id. So If I get it right, I need to just compare "thread_game_id" and "game_id" which I got from TURN_END

Comment: I updated the example to contain a game ID. Then when stop is called it sets the game id and the waiting thread only stops if it not zero. But It think you should also remove the function call to `start()` from inside `end()`. This is not the right way to run a thread. What is better is to have a loop inside your `start()` function which parses the flag/cv for events (values for the flag) and does not return until end is called...

Comment: You can see my edit now too... As you can see I request new game_id after I start a new thread and then have it from user message (it's actually in user session in my real implementation now in the message). So I need only stop particular game_id but not all game_ids and I don't need mutex lock another game threads as well..  @code_fodder

Comment: @featureoffuture hmm.. I really don't think this is doing what you expect it to be doing. You are creating threads all over the place. I don't have your socket implementation so I can't really test it for you, but this really looks like a mess of threads! - I fear you are going to get into a confusing situation really quickly. Your code looks simple, but the outcome is not. I'll post one more example - using stdin instead of your socket (so that I can run it) which displays exactly what is going on in each thread....

Comment: I use libwebsockets library which is C library (not C++) so I have to use i because it's better than other alternatives for C++. I think you're right about recursion now I know how to get rid of that. And conditional variable. But I have a bad practical knowledge about multithreading. My concern about your code is mutex. Because as far as I know it blocks execution for the same method from other threads at the same time. If yes I see it's not useful because all the games should be completely parallel  @code_fodder

Comment: @featureoffuture ok, but the sockets part is irrelevant to this particular issue. So I have added a stdin implementation for you. Just replace the stdin part for your socket input. This is still quite rough, but now at least your "start" function will implement a thread more correctly in a loop and you games can end their turns per game or you can exit all games...

Comment: Looks very relevant. But I need a time to play for myself. It would be nice if you update your example so it accepts game_id to end turn from stdin as well. So it would be more precise thing to my problem...

Comment: @featureoffuture getting the game ID will require string parsing that is not relevant because you get the game ID from your message. Just extract the game ID from your message and assign it to `the_game_id` where I have hard-coded it to `1` and you are done. I have shown in the example and in the output that I can control all game threads exactly as I want. Now its up to you  : )

Comment: Sure. I'm just worrying that we use this global scope variable that all threads are sharing with each other! But I see mutex there. Should it actually work reliable in parallel? @code_fodder

Comment: @featureoffuture yes, but you probably want to put mutex's around the main thread where is sets `the_game_id`. But as I said, this is a rough example. There are still many ways to improve it. But to pass signals between threads you eventually need some sort of global/static flag (or shared memory or such)...  Doing it how you where will lead to something bad!

Comment: Hey. You solution is brilliant. But... I have a bit other condition I need analyse couple timeouts at the same place. Is it possible? @code_fodder

Comment: Yes, you can create a simple timer class which basically runs in a seperate thread (e.g. first hit on google:  https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/) pass your timeout and a function to run. But I think you need to post a new question. Remember to post all your code and the output you expect along with a detailed description of your problem...